# Alternative to pcomplete in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, completion

I'm new to org-mode and really need to figure out how to get completion working for stuff like `:tags` and `#+` options. Apparently org uses pcomplete as the completion backend. Indeed `M-x pcomplete` (helm) does offer a buffer with long list of completions for #+ (which disappears if you try to expand the buffer). You then have to click on one of the options, which feels pretty kind of clumsy.

Is there a feature complete and mature alternative to pcomplete? I'm used to completions just popping up as I type, and would ideally like to get the same functionality in Org. Alternately, am I using pcomplete wrong?

## Update

Here's the full code:

```
(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions 'pcomplete-completions-at-point nil t))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-mode-hook)
```

It works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you've configured Emacs so that "completions just pop up", but possibly

```
(add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions 'pcomplete-completions-at-point)
```

will do it. If you use `company` for completions (as I do) and you have `company-capf` in `company-backends` (it should be there by default I believe) `company` should pick up `pcomplete` completions via `completion-at-point`.

You may also be interested in "Easy templates"; see http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-templates.html#Easy-templates.